# How are multiple inputs of the same activity to a product handled when a database is imported?

Tags: brightway

For example, multiple inputs of the same "market for tap water, RoW" activity are used as for different purposes during an industrial process. Are the amounts of these inputs automatically summed up under one "market for tap water, RoW" activity, when the database is imported?

Thank you!

[Edited]
I added a code example to better illustrate the question:

```py
##the goal is to use a dict to categorize the inputs of the activity "market for tap water, RoW" by industrial classifications. 
##For example, there could be 200+ upstream activities under the classification "3510b: Electric power generation, photovoltaic" 
##using this particular tap water activity. Then the results will be "d['3510b...']=[1E-5, 2E-7,...].

#get tap water of interest
tap_water=db.search('tap water',filter={"location":"row"})[0]
#create a dict to store classifications 
facet_store=defaultdict(list)

#find the upstream activities
for exc in tap_water.upstream():
    temp_classification=exc.output["classifications"]
    flat_classification_list=[el for tuuple in temp_classification for el in tuuple]
    temp_locator=flat_classification_list.index("ISIC rev.4 ecoinvent") #keyword for location
    key_classification=flat_classification_list[temp_locator+1] #actual classification is always immediately after this keyword
    facet_store[key_classification].append(exc["amount"]) #append the input amount of tap water to each upstream activity to the list
```

The question is what if there is a upstream activity that uses "market for tap water, RoW" more than once. Does that mean this upstream activity will show up more than once as 'exc' in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

No, such summing up would require work, and laziness is a virtue for programmers. Keeping such exchanges separate is necessary for handling multiple uncertainty distributions, or just for making datasets clearer (e.g. we have the same thing for any activity which has losses, where there is one production exchange and one consumption exchange of the same flow).

Comment: Thank you, Chris! Does that mean there may be repeated upstream activities in "market for tap water, RoW".upstream()? (Because different amounts of "market for tap water, RoW" are used for the same upstream activity more than once)

Comment: Sure, you can add as many as you need. No real reason to introduce restrictions, to Brightway doesn't.

Comment: Thx again, Chris. I think I have not illustrate the question well enough. Please see the edited content of the question.